# Can't figure out problem with Excel VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

I am fairly new to writing code in excel VBA. Most of this code is some I have tried to replicated based on what other people have wrote. The problem I am having is I have a quantity counter and when a barcode is scanned into the cell (A4) it will add the barcode to a new cell (Starts at C8 and goes down) and if this barcode is already scanned once and is scanned again it will add one to the quantity. Now I am trying to add a date and time next to it as a barcode is scanned. This works but has an issue I can't figure out. The barcode must be scanned twice for the date to appear in the proper cell. This is an issue because it raises the quantity up one more than it should. Please help.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Select Case Target.Address
        Case "$A$4"
            If Target.Value <> "" Then
                On Error Resume Next
                Set xitem = Range("C8", Range("C" & Rows.Count) _
                    .End(xlUp)).Find(Range("A4").Value)
                With xitem.Offset(0, -1)
                    .Value = .Value + 1
                    .Offset(0, 1).Select
                End With

                With xitem.Offset(0, 1)
                    .Value = Date & "  " & Time
                    .NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy h:mm AM/PM"
                End With

                On Error GoTo 0
                If xitem Is Nothing Then
                    With Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                        .Value = Target.Value
                        .Offset(0, -1) = 1
                    End With

                End If
                Range("A4") = ""
                Range("A4").Select
            End If
```

Adds quantity

```
Case "$C$4"
            If Target.Value <> "" Then
                On Error Resume Next
                Set xitem = Range("C8", Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)) _
                    .Find(Range("C4").Value)
                With xitem.Offset(0, -1)
                    .Value = .Value - 1
                End With

                If xitem Is Nothing Then MsgBox Target & " cannot be found " _
                    & "and cannot be removed."
                Range("C4") = ""
                Range("C4").Select
                On Error GoTo 0
            End If
```

Removes quantity (I am going to add an out time to this just trying to get the initial scan time in first)

```
Case "$E$4"  'find
            If Target.Value <> "" Then
                On Error Resume Next
                Set xitem = Range("C8", Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)) _
                    .Find(Range("E4").Value)
                If xitem Is Nothing Then
                    MsgBox Target & " was not found."
                    Range("E4").Select
                End If
                Range("E4") = ""
                xitem.Select
                On Error GoTo 0
            End If
    End Select
End Sub
```

This is what I am using to take me directly to a barcode that has already been scanned.

Sorry if this post is badly formatted never posted before. Any and all help with this issue is appreciated. A photo of the spread sheet is also attached.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code to see what happens at run time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are repeating some things within your code which you only need to do once, like the `Find()` for example.

Here's one alternative approach:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Adding As Boolean, Finding As Boolean, Subtracting As Boolean
    Dim f As Range, v

    Select Case Target.Address(True, True)
        Case "$A$4": Adding = True
        Case "$C$4": Subtracting = True
        Case "$E$4": Finding = True
        Case Else: Exit Sub
    End Select

    v = Trim(Target.Value)
    If Len(v) = 0 Then Exit Sub


    Set f = Me.Range("C8").Resize(1000, 1).Find(v, lookat:=xlWhole)

    If Adding Then

        If f Is Nothing Then
            'not found: add as new row
            Set f = Me.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            f.Value = v
        End If
        f.Offset(0, 1).Value = f.Offset(0, 1).Value + 1
        doDate f.Offset(0, -1)
        Target.Value = ""

    ElseIf Subtracting Then

        If f Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox v & " not found for subtraction!"
        Else
            f.Offset(0, 1).Value = f.Offset(0, 1).Value - 1
            doDate f.Offset(0, -1)
            Target.Value = ""
        End If

    Else 'finding
        If Not f Is Nothing Then
            f.EntireRow.Select
            Target.Value = ""
        Else
            MsgBox v & " not found."
        End If
    End If

    If Adding Or Subtracting Then Target.Select

End Sub

Sub doDate(c As Range)
    With c
        .NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy h:mm AM/PM"
        .Value = Now
    End With
End Sub
```